# let mapleader = "\<Space>" not working arch linux

Tags: vim, arch-linux, gvim

I'm trying to map space bar to leader key by using the code above but there's a problem - whenever I press space, the pointer moves forward a character, which annoys me. What am I missing? (gvim@arch linux) Here's my .vimrc

```
let mapleader = "\<Space>"

nnoremap <Leader> :w<CR>
```

Comment: Please don't cross post.

Comment: I don't think mappings can start with a space. I certainly haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: @Heptite I have no problem when setting mapleader set to space. All the mappings work (Although you might see the cursor move) if you only changed map leader. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341062/vim-let-mapleader-space-annoying-cursor-movement

Comment: @FDinoff: Odd. I couldn't get any mappings with a leading space to work until I restarted Vim. Looks like I found a hard to reproduce bug.

Comment: @Heptite where you changing map leader after all the mappings were defined? From `:h map leader` "Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping is defined. Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already defined mappings." Or were you trying something else?

Answer (score 1):

add

```
nnoremap <SPACE> <Nop>
```

before setting mapleader. Without that, pressing `<Space>` will not behave like other keys as mapleader. `<Space>` in normal mode is mapped to `<right>`. Just press `<space>` a couple of times in a row and you will see undesired behaviour.

Tip:

Instead of setting `<mapleader>` to space, map (:map, not :noremap) space to `<leader>`. That way something will pop up in the showcmd corner. It's awesome!

[From vim subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2d2za5/question_about_having_spacebar_as_leader/)